# why is my fixed element invisible, when the webpage is to short?

Tags: html, css

**GOAL:**
a div is

```
{ position:fixed; bottom:0% }
```

it has a real height and width; the z-index is the highest in the document
= therefore it should be visible everytime!

**PROBLEM:**
mobile browsers 'cut' the bottom end of the page when zooming out.
but this also cuts my div! While zooming in or out, I can see how the bottom-border makes the div appear/disappear.

**MY INTERPRETATION:**
it looks to me like the body of the page has an `overflow:hide` and my fixed div is pushed outside the area of the body when zooming out.
unfortunately, I can't change the body(I only inject the div into an existing site and have no connection with the code of this page)

Would be happy with any explanations/&suggestions/&ideas!
thanks.

**EDIT**
I checked the height of the viewport, the html-document and the finally visible amount of css-pixel *when zoomed out to maximum*:

```
1440 document.documentElement.clientHeight
1486 document.documentElement.offsetHeight
1566 window.innerHeight
```

so,the mobile devices seem to '**cut**' the `fixed-div`, because it's OUTSIDE THE HTML !?!

**EDIT 2**
I *deactivated* the existing 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` 
(not a real option for later) and saw, that now also my dev-tools in chrome show the 'end' of the hmtl/body. Everything what is more south is not visible; instead of I get a very empty whitespace.

Comment: sorry, not online and from my work . . .

Comment: Try with position:absolute

Comment: you know, than my fixed div is not fixed anymore, i.e. not positioning absolute to the window, instead absolute to the document and therefor somewhere else . . .

Comment: It's looking in a glass ball without code. Should work as expected from the info here. Fixed position only relates to the screen so there must be something about the div itself.

Comment: yes, the fixed position works fine (related to the screen); but why is the html/body too short ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line as the first line after head starts

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```